python extension not loading in vscode
I have seen this question and this one
Neither help me
When I add the python extension for vscode, the status line states
python extension loading ...

But it never does
I have removed all extensions from vscode and deleted all ms-python files from .config, removed and reinstalled vscode
I am running python 3.12.4 on manjaro
code - OSS

Version: 1.91.1
Commit: f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729
Date: 2024-07-12T15:10:53.972Z
Electron: 29.4.5
ElectronBuildId: undefined
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.6.41-1-MANJARO

Can anyone help?

I have now switched to flatpak vscode and it works well

Possibly related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78886125/vscode-python-extension-stuck-on-reactivating-terminals/78886126#78886126

A possible solution for manjaro: you could run command sudo pacman -S python python-pip python-setuptools python-virtualenv to install the Required Dependencies

After reading this answer I have moved from  code-oss to the flatpak version - seems ok so far
