VSCode Python extension loading forever, saying “Reactivating terminals”
After updating VS code to v1.92, the Python extension consistently fails to launch, indefinitely showing a spinner next to “Reactivating terminals…” on the status bar.
Selecting OUTPUT > Python reveals the error Failed to resolve env "/mnt/data-linux/miniconda3".
Here’s the error trace:
2024-08-07 18:35:35.873 [error] sendStartupTelemetry() failed. s [Error]: Failed to resolve env "/mnt/data-linux/miniconda3"
    at ae (/home/user/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.12.2-linux-x64/out/client/extension.js:2:1968174)
    at oe (/home/user/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.12.2-linux-x64/out/client/extension.js:2:1966134)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/user/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.12.2-linux-x64/out/client/extension.js:2:1962428)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21) {
  code: -4,
  data: undefined
}

How do I fix this? Restarting worked, but that's not sustainable.

I had old python related settings in my user settings JSON, deleted all of them and the problem was resolved.

This appears to be a bug related to the new "native" Python locator.
You can go back to the old working version by adding the following line to the user settings JSON (until the bug in the native locator is fixed):
"python.locator": "js",

Note that this workaround pins you to the legacy version which is not something you'll want to have around forever so you might want to report your issue on Github at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues.
There've been many issues already filed and many solved but it's a work in progress. Example issues:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23922
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23963
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23956


I am seeing this error on v2024.14.1

Thanks @JamesHirschorn for letting me know, it would be great if you could provide debugging information for the developers here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23922

I am on v2024.20.0 of the extension and it is not fixed for me. Had to switch to js. Newest version of VSCode installed, I am on MacOS 15.1.

Thanks for the comment @Wizard, I'll remove the solved part. It's solved in some cases but new implementation still buggy it seems.

I am in VSCode version 1.95.3. 'gd' to go to the definition using the VS Code NeoVim extension, which was not working for me. After  "python.locator": "js", this is working. Thanks.

These steps solved my issue:

Open VS Code Settings
search for Python Locator
switch from native to js.
restart the vs code



That's the same as the accepted answer just using the UI instead of JSON. Thanks!

In my case, it was a corrupted .venv dir.
When I ran source .venv/Scripts/activate in Git Bash, it looked like it was working, but it was actually silently failing. When I ran which python, it showed /c/Program Files/Python312/python instead of the .venv dir.
The solution was to recreate the .venv dir:
rm -r .venv
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/Scripts/activate
which python

Now, it is pointing to the .venv dir. Then restarting VS Code, it was able to find the venv and no more hanging "Reactivating terminals..." I did not have to change the python.locator, it is still set to native.

Exactly my case! Removed venv dir to share the code, but later noticed this annoying “Reactivating terminals”

The bug has been fixed in the Python extension version v2024.14.1 - so you just need to update the extension and reload the extension host.
Setting the locator to js is a workaround that pins to the legacy resolution method which will become less well supported over time. So updating is most likely the best solution for everyone now.
Here's how to update the python extension to the latest version*


I dont think the accepted answer solves this for the most part bcs you can fix this without doing that.
As per other posts here state: it is related to python extension finding virtual envs, but removing the env is will not solve all problems either and there may be other reasons it fails so you need to read the log.
On remote sessions the cause may be a missing virtualenv to begin with so there is nothing to remove.
REMOTE SESSIONS NOT INITIALIZING
If your remote session on one host has this problem, but others work fine, it is due to corruption in the remote server, Actually in the session cache $HOME/.vscode-server/ dir  on that host.  To fix that, just delete or move that (mv $HOME/.vscode-server/ $HOME/old_vscode-server/) and restart the remote session. That will clear the problem allowing you to select a new virtual env for projects.
THE LOGS
The logs for this can be found on the remote machine under
$HOME/.vscode-server/data/logs/<datestamp>/exthost1/ms-python.python/Python\ Locator.log

mine had this message which caused the whole problem for just this host.
2024-12-17 22:00:18.595 [error] Failed to execute Python to resolve info "/tmp/.555/bin/python": No such file or directory (os error 2)
2024-12-17 22:00:18.595 [warning] Unknown Python Env "/tmp/.555/bin/python"
2024-12-17 22:00:18.595 [error] Failed to resolve env "/tmp/.555/bin/python"

you can also look a the log from the vscode OUTPUT terminal, and selecting the drop down "Python Language Server".


Interestingly, in my case the feature is "Experimental" and it was set to "native". Switching it to "js" seemed to resolve the issue, but the python seems to be lost as it is not picked up from terminal.

Same problem here...the link below solved it for me.

In VS Code, type Ctrl + Shift + P
Type Python: Clear Cache
Select option Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23922#issuecomment-2523255885
