Reactivating Terminal notification not going away on VSC
I installed python extension on visual studio code and restarting terminal isn't going away. While digging in deep, I found this error as well, attaching the picture of the same. enter image description here
I tried uninstalling and installing VSC, Python, Python extension again but it didn't help.

Does the python.exe in the directory work properly?

do you mean cmd?

Try the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78886125/vscode-python-extension-loading-forever-saying-reactivating-terminals/78886126#78886126

Checkout this link for some insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78886125/vscode-python-extension-loading-forever-saying-reactivating-terminals
